# Why are the bears bulgy?

Tags: character-analysis, meaning, c-s-lewis, the-chronicles-of-narnia

Among the diverse characters introduced in *Prince Caspian* during Caspian's tour of the Old Narnians are three bears known as the "Bulgy Bears". What exactly does it mean for them to be *bulgy*? It's not a word I've seen used very much, but presumably they bulge somehow - in what way do they bulge? What does this tell us about the characters?

Comment: Probably that they are overweight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you google "algy met a bear" you will get thousands of hits on the traditional "Algy met a bear, the bear met Algy.  The bear was bulgy, the bulge was Algy".  If you look up pre-1940 *bulgy bear* in Google books you get  hits, such as this one in [Everybody's Magazine](https://books.google.com/books?id=vnAXAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA88&dq=bulgy+bear&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3goSa1ffVAhVr8IMKHbZTBCIQ6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=bulgy%20bear&f=false) with some version of a bear meeting  Benjy, with predictable results.

Not that our Narnian bears would do such a thing: I'm sure their bulge came from eating too much honey.

From which I conclude: when *Prince Caspian* was written, "Bulgy bear" was a known thing, appropriated & repurposed by CSL.